# Need algorithm to find optimal lower and upper bounds to enclose set of numbers

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have a collection of numbers.  After each update, one number from the collection is removed and another number is added.  After each update, I want to know the upper and lower bounds that best encloses the numbers in the collection with the constraint that the distance between the upper and lower bounds is always a fixed width and never changes.  The maximum width of the enclosing bound will be a parameter to the algorithm.  Further, I know that the domain of all numbers observed will always fall within some other wider fixed lower (DL) and upper bound (DU).  So the problem can be solved by simply setting the lower bound == DL and upper bound == DL + width of enclosing bounds, computing the number of points inside the bounds and comparing against all other positions until the upper bounds == DU, then select the position that encloses the most points.  However, is there a more efficient algorithm to do this that takes advantage of the fact that the state only changes by 1 element between each update?

Background / Motivation: The purpose of this algorithm is to implement an adaptive binary search.  Depending on observed data, it may be possible to adaptively reduce the search range of a binary search in order to complete the search in fewer steps.

For example, say I want to program an automated wafer tester to characterize the minimum voltage with which a part can pass a given test.  Assume that the part will consistently fail at all voltages below a threshold voltage and pass at all voltages above that threshold voltage.  In that case, I can use a binary search to find that threshold voltage.  It might also be the case that although I am required to search across a wide range of voltages, say 1.0V to 2V, I might find that on a large sample of thresholds collected during testing, that most of the data falls within the range of 1.0V to 1.5V and rarely falls outside that range.  Then in that case, I can reduce my search range to 1.0V to 1.5V with the condition that if it fails at 1.5V, then I'll need to repeat the search across 1.5V to 2.0V to cover the full range.  In that case, when I guess wrong, I end up having to effectively do the search twice.  However, if I am right that the real data falls within 1.0V to 1.5V most of the time, then by being able to cut my effective search range in half for most cases, I can save one iteration of the binary search and reduce the overall cost of performing the test.

I tried to keep the problem description as general and concise as possible above, but that's what I am trying to do.  Given a full search range defined by DL and DU, I would like to know the most likely continuous subrange of that full range that is exactly half the width of the full range based on the last N observed points.  I would then look at what percentage of those past N datapoints actually fall within that range to estimate the likelihood of making a correct guess to determine if I should use the subrange or not (as in some cases, the data may span most of the full range and this strategy could backfire).  Key point: I'm only interested in subranges that are an exact power of 2 smaller than the full range (0.5, 0.25, 0.125, etc).  Reason being is that if I am able to reduce my search range by only 40%, that will not allow me to reduce the number of steps in my binary search.  I can only save a step when I can cut the search range by half or more.

Comment: Keep the elements in a sorted array. On each update, locate the insertion point (P1) and deletion point (P2) with binary searches. The elements between P1 and P2 should be moved towards P2 to fill the hole at P2, and leave a hole at P1. Place the new element at P1. Finally, use a sliding window algorithm to find the best upper and lower bounds.

Comment: @user3386109 Thanks, that might be the best algorithm.  Only way I can think of improving it is to somehow replace the sliding window algorithm with a constant time lookup.  But I'm not sure if that's possible.  I'll implement your solution for now unless someone can improve on it.

Comment: Do you have more info on the constraints? Namely, the fixed size of the collection, the 'fixed width', the size of the full range DU-DL, and the number of updates?

Comment: If DU-DL is small enough that you can create an array of that many integers in memory, a Segment Tree data structure lets you do updates and queries in log(DU-DL) time.

Comment: @kcsquared I added details about the background and motivation of this problem.  Fixed width will be half the full range (DU-DL) or possibly a quarter of the full range if most of the data can fit in a quarter of the range.  But in most cases, it will only be half.  Size of the collection to use will be an algorithm parameter: tradeoff between responsiveness or weighting of new samples vs. not missing outliers.  I'll look up Segment Tree.  I have not heard of it before.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: (1/2) Can I suggest a different tack? You're looking for a binary search algorithm that is fast on average for an approximately known distribution. There's a close connection between binary search algorithms and binary [prefix codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_code) whose encoding map preserves order.

Comment: (2/2) The traditional binary search algorithm minimizes the length of the longest code. But if you know (approximately) what the distribution is, then it’s possible to be more efficient on average: each time, try the threshold that is the weighted median of the distribution conditioned on being in the range consistent with the previous queries. (To ensure a worst case of at most q queries, make sure that every outcome has probability at least 2^−q.) This is theoretically as efficient as you can be on average.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat, thanks David. Could you give me an example of how that search would work? I'm trying to understand the "each time, try the threshold that is the weighted median of the distribution conditioned on being in the range consistent with the previous queries" part. So for the first iteration, I test the previous weighted median...if I find that to be a pass, how do I calculate my next test point?  Same question for the fail case.

Comment: @PentiumPro200 You use the weighted median of the samples consistent with the query results so far. So if the part fails at 1.5, you use the median of everything greater than 1.5, for example. I mumbled something about minimum probabilities before, but IMO a better way to do the fail-safe is, set the maximum number of queries q that you’re willing to make, and after k queries, don’t accept a query that leaves more than 2^(q−k) elements on one side, adjusting it toward the unweighted median.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Thanks David. That sounds like a good approach. The only concern that I have is that I may end up reducing my search range by far less than half on each iteration on average.  For example, if my range is 1V to 2V and I calculate my median to be 1.3V, then I'll either reduce my search range by 70% or 30% whereas the binary search guarantees a reduction of 50% on every iteration. I'll implement it though and see how it does. Maybe a hybrid approach -- choose median for first few iterations and then switch to binary could be best.

Comment: Do you really **need** to do this? Binary search is very fast, being an `O(log n)` algorithm with small constant factors. This means that halving the search range will only decrease the number of iterations it performs in the worst case by 1, as you've also noticed. Whatever optimizations you find, chances are that implementing them will increase the constant factors in your program and cost you at least as much execution time as you'll save in the actual binary search. I would focus on the actual implementation rather than algorithmic improvements here. What hardware will you run this on?

Comment: @IVlad The binary search that I am referring to in the problem statement is not performed on data in memory, but rather on test equipment that can take as much as several seconds per iteration. So if I can spend a few hundred microseconds to save a few seconds, it's definitely worth it.